# Has_many class name not working like I thought?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a user and post model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sent_posts, :class_name => 'Post'
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

The problem is that in the console, if I do

```
User.first.sent_posts.empty?
```

it returns True.

But if I do this in my view

```
<%= @user.sent_posts.empty? %>
```

it returns False. Any ideas why this is happening? It works fine if I just use

```
has_many :posts
```

on its own.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. It was to do with having an @user.sent_posts.build in the controller! Doh.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that User.first and @user are the same User model record?